# Issue when using concat with commas

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

I have a table with values, primary keys are unique ids with increment.
Secondly I have another table that saves the ids from the first table along with other data. The ids are stored in a already_used column
the already_used column should look like this: 1,2,3,4,5,6....

Now I use a query with CONCAT to fill the already_used column with data:

```
UPDATE table2 SET already_used = CONCAT(already_used,', ". $id ."') WHERE id = $table_id
```

Now my problem is that if the already_used column is empty, concat will produce an output like this: ,1,2,3,4,5,6...

So there is a comma in front of the first value. How can I ajust the query so the first value doesn't actually get a comma in front of it?

Later I store the already_used data in a variable using PHP and then I want to find all rows from table1 that weren't already used using a NOT IN statement:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN($variable)
```

And if there's a comma in front it will give a mysql error.

Comment: What are you trying to do? As @juergend said in his answer this is an horrible design. You should perhaps ask about your need and not about your attempted solution. See [What is an XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `IF` or `CASE` to test `already_used` before concatenating:

```
UPDATE table2
SET already_used = IF(already_used = '', '$id', CONCAT(already_used, ',$id'))
WHERE id = $table_id
```

In your second query, you should use `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON FIND_IN_SET(t1.id, t2.already_used)
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

However, FIND_IN_SET can't be indexed. This is why a relation table is usually a much better design.

Answer (score 1):

### Never store multiple values in a single column. Never!

Please change your DB desgin to store only one `id` per record in `table2`.

Comment: I know it is bad design but otherwise I would have several million entries per day and I need all that info.

Comment: So instead of several million entries, you'll have a column that's thousands of characters long.

Comment: A DB can handle millions of entries with proper indexing with no problem at all! You will only have real pain if you store multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table2 WHEN already_used IS NULL THEN SET already_used = CONCAT(already_used,'". $id ."') WHEN already_used IS NOT NULL THEN SET already_used = CONCAT(already_used,', ". $id ."') WHERE id = $table_id
```